# Cannot share folder between pc and laptop even they see each others

Tags: network-shares, shared-folders

I have PC and Laptop ,
I wanted to share files from PC and access them from Laptop through ethernet cable ,

I connected to internet via Laptop Wi-Fi and connect ethernet cable between PC and Laptop ,

I do share internet from wi-fi to ethernet and both devices connected to internet without any issue, but can no longer be able to access shared folders,

when I turned off the wi-fi both devices can see shared files but when turn on wi-fi they can't access shared folders

I need to be able to access shared folders even when I turned on the wi-fi?

Comment: Is your Wi-Fi broadcasting a different network than the one your PC is connected to? Check ipconfig and determine if they are on the same subnet. Then make sure your shared folder is setup with the correct permissions, both share and NTFS.

Comment: Yes cuz my laptop share internet to pc via ethernet cable => Network connections => wi-fi => prop => sharing => allow other... ethernet . then my pc take IP start with 192.168.137 but my laptop start with => wireless lan IPV4 192.168.100 and Ethernet adapter 192.168.137

Comment: I would try hard coding static IP addresses on the ethernet side and using that.  First try 10.x.x.x range and leave the 192.168.x.x for the wifi.  Also, many laptops (and other) have this stupid toggle that disables the "other adapter" when one gets activated making it a pain to use both at the same time.

Comment: It looks like they not working together at the same time (Wifi with ethernet)